# Ubuntu in Virtualbox access using Winscp for SFTP

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 16 inside of Windows 7 oracle virtualbox.Ubuntu is up and running well.Below response comes for the ip address

```
/sbin/ifconfig
inet addr:*.*.2.15 Bcast: *.*.2.255
```

But when I tried to communicate from

```
windows command prompt using ping *.*.2.15
```

it gives timeout.Please give your response.

Answer (score 0):

is that IP address 10.0.2.15 your mentioning?  If that's the case then you cant ping that IP address. It is because the IP address is in a separate network created by virtual box. You can only port forward the requests.

More info:
http://trainenv.blogspot.in/2016/03/virtual-networking.html